# How to get item value from the selected items using QTreeView?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Hello I've problem using qtreeview. So I want get the value from the selected item and save all value from selected row to array. I do not know what code should I write when the user clicks the edit button. Please help me what code should I write in the line `void Teachers::editTeacher ()?`. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include "mainwindow/teacherspage/teachers.h"
#include "mainwindow/teacherspage/crud_teacher.h"

using namespace std;

Teachers::Teachers(QWidget* parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    proxyModel_ = new QSortFilterProxyModel;

    proxyView_ = new QTreeView;
    proxyView_->setRootIsDecorated(false);
    proxyView_->setAlternatingRowColors(true);
    proxyView_->setModel(proxyModel_);
    proxyView_->setSortingEnabled(true);
    proxyView_->sortByColumn(1, Qt::AscendingOrder);

    filterPatternLineEdit_ = new QLineEdit;
    filterPatternLabel_ = new QLabel("Cari data:");

    filterColumnComboBox_ = new QComboBox;
    filterColumnComboBox_->addItem("No Induk");
    filterColumnComboBox_->addItem("Nama");
    filterColumnComboBox_->setFixedWidth(200);

    addButton_ = new QPushButton("Tambah");
    addButton_->setFixedWidth(100);
    editButton_ = new QPushButton("Edit");
    editButton_->setFixedWidth(100);
    deleteButton_ = new QPushButton("Hapus");
    deleteButton_->setFixedWidth(80);
    reloadButton_ = new QPushButton();
    reloadButton_->setIcon(QIcon(":/images/reload.png"));
    reloadButton_->setFixedWidth(20);

    connect(filterPatternLineEdit_, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)),
            this, SLOT(filterRegExpChanged()));
    connect(filterColumnComboBox_, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)),
            this, SLOT(filterColumnChanged()));
    connect(addButton_, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(addTeacher()));
    connect(editButton_, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(editTeacher()));
    connect(deleteButton_, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(deleteTeacher()));
    connect(reloadButton_, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(reloadTeacher()));

    QVBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    QHBoxLayout *filterLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    QHBoxLayout *sourceLayout = new QHBoxLayout;

    filterLayout->addWidget(filterPatternLabel_, 1);
    filterLayout->addWidget(filterPatternLineEdit_, 2);
    filterLayout->addWidget(filterColumnComboBox_, 3);
    filterLayout->addWidget(addButton_, 4);
    filterLayout->addWidget(editButton_, 5);
    filterLayout->addWidget(deleteButton_, 6);
    filterLayout->addWidget(reloadButton_, 7);
    sourceLayout->addWidget(proxyView_);

    mainLayout->addLayout(filterLayout);
    mainLayout->addLayout(sourceLayout);
    setLayout(mainLayout);

    teachersModel = new TeachersModel(this);
    try {
        SetSourceModel(teachersModel->CreateTeacherModel());
    } catch (exception& e) {
        qDebug() << "Caught " << e.what();
        QMessageBox::critical(this, "Error", e.what());
    }
}

void Teachers::filterRegExpChanged()
{
    QRegExp regExp(filterPatternLineEdit_->text(), Qt::CaseInsensitive, QRegExp::RegExp);
    proxyModel_->setFilterRegExp(regExp);
}

void Teachers::filterColumnChanged()
{
    proxyModel_->setFilterKeyColumn(filterColumnComboBox_->currentIndex());
}

void Teachers::SetSourceModel(QAbstractItemModel* model)
{
    proxyModel_->setSourceModel(model);
    proxyView_->setColumnHidden(9, true);
}

void Teachers::addTeacher()
{
    CrudTeacher *crudTeacher = new CrudTeacher(this);
    crudTeacher->show();
}

void Teachers::editTeacher()
{

}

void Teachers::deleteTeacher()
{

}

void Teachers::reloadTeacher()
{
    delete teachersModel;
    TeachersModel *teachersModel = new TeachersModel(this);
    SetSourceModel(teachersModel->CreateTeacherModel());
}


Teachers::~Teachers() {}
```

And this is the result program:
[image: Result Program]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you could use [QAbstractItemModel::data](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#data) with the views current index.
Since `QModelIndex` also contains the colum, you have to call it once for every colum:

```
QList<QVariant> teacherData;
QModelIndex tIndex = proxyModel_->mapToSource(proxyView_->currentIndex());
for(int i = 0; i < teachersModel->rowCount(); i++)
{
    QModelIndex columnIndex = teachersModel->sibling(tIndex.row(), i, tIndex);
    teacherData.append(teachersModel->data(columnIndex);
}
```

I don't know the model youre using, but wouldn't it be easier to add a function to it that simply returns the complete row, using the current index? For example, if you're using a list to store you're data, it could look like that:

```
//In the header file
private:
    QList<Teacher> teachers; //or something similar

//in the .cpp file
QList<QVariant> getTeacherData(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    QList<QVariant> data;
    Teacher t = this->teachers[index.row()];
    data.append(t.name); //as an example, use your own fields
    //...
    return data;
}
```